# DAX - Last value in a Horizontal hierarchy

Tags: powerbi, dax

Having trouble replicating an Excel function to DAX.

Say I have the below table(view image link). The rows vary in depth and for each row I wanted to know the last value in the hierarchy, I could use a lookup e.g "=LOOKUP(2,1/(XX:XX<>""),XX:XX)".

[[Image of table]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6C8Z.png)

How would one achieve this in DAX?

Thanks.

Comment: Did not know the table would turn out like this. currently trying to edit it.

Comment: I gave up formatting the table and added a link to an image of it :)

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of this requeriment but you can do that using calculated columns.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta The last value in the hierarchy is the group the person belongs to. This differs in depth from person to person. Some people are further down the chain than others. I therefore need the last filled value within the horizontal hierarchy for each row to know which group each person belongs to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine a combination of SWITCH and ISBLANK functions would get this done.  Just beware that BLANK etc in DAX is a bit unintuitive/inconsistent, e.g.

https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/blank-handling-in-dax/

Comment: Thanks for this, however I have made a compromise and decided to do this in Excel prior to importing to Power Bi. I will give this a try and see if I can get it working though.

Comment: If DAX isn't your thing, you could tackle this with automation in the PBI Query Editor, e.g. select columns in reverse order, then Add Column / Merge columns, then Split Column and only keep the 1st result.

Comment: Ah brilliant idea I will go with that to take out the analysis required in Excel. Will mark this as the solution based on that. Thanks.